# Django: When I try to take input within url using path() showing invalid syntax

Tags: django, django-urls

I tried to take an integer input within the url in urls.py and take it to views.py
this is the code I did :

urlpatterns = [
....
path('dater/plus/int:offset/' , views.timeahead, name='timeahead'  )
....
]

but it is showing syntax error at this path.
This is my first question on stack overflow, I'm just a beginner pardon me for any blunders I make.

Comment: /int:offset/ ----> /<int:offset>/

Comment: can you upload the view for this url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
 path('dater/plus/int:offset/' , views.timeahead, name='timeahead')
```

use

```
path('dater/plus/<int:offset>', views.timeahead, name='timeahead')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, sorry for the late reply your annswer works